# How to prevent Docker's container from being stopped after exiting a /bin/bash session

Tags: bash, docker, clojure, dockerfile, leiningen

How to prevent Docker's container from being stopped after exiting a `/bin/bash` session provided as an `ENTRYPOINT`?

What I mean. Suppose that I have a web service written in Clojure and I want to wrap it in a container. This is how the `Dockerfile` will look then:

```
FROM pandeiro/lein
MAINTAINER some <some@email.com>
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN git clone https://github.com/some/some.git && cd web-service && lein deps
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

The reason I made a `/bin/bash` an entry point is that the user should make some changes to the web service's config file first.

When we do `docker run -p 443:443 -t -i container-name`, it opens a `/bin/bash` session where we can install a text editor, make some changes to the config file and run the web service via `lein run`. But the problem is that when we close the `bash` session the whole Docker container is stopped so the web service will not be available anymore.

What can I do in such case? And what other flaws do you see in the example I've provided?

Comment: change the entrypoint, as long as it is bash, you have no solution

Comment: @user2915097 Which entry point should I use then? I need to provide a way for the user to edit the config before running the `web-service`

Comment: maybe a shell script containing a bash session and then your `lein run`

Comment: Why don't you mount the configuration file into your container using docker volumes (https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)?

Comment: @gtonic Could you elaborate please? If I just "map" the volume from the host computer that contains the `config` file to the `web-service`s directory the whole dir's content will be overwritten with that config file

Comment: @FrozenHeart: its also possible to mount a single file (e.g. -v ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history ').

Comment: @gtonic That's great but it's not that user-friendly, you know. The user should create a copy of the `web-service` config by itself and then map it to the container's one. Is there another option?

Comment: @FrozenHeart not really anything user-friendly ;(

Comment: @gtonic Well, how is it usually handled in other containers provided by other people then?

Comment: @FrozenHeart: you could launch an initial 'configuration page' as default, to  collect the data. then redirect/boot your real service. this whole (wizard) logic would remain within your service. the jenkins docker image would be a good example to look at.

Comment: @gtonic I think that it's not enough in my case, unfortunately. The user in my case should place an SSL certificate to the `web-service`'s directory as well, so just answering some questions is not what I'm actually looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123120/discussion-between-gtonic-and-frozenheart).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your /bin/bash is started as PID1 by docker. The PID1 process receives the SIGINT and SIGKILL and is responsible for killing sub-processes. To get around that you can start your application with `exec` which will install it as the PID1 process instead of bash.

You should also automate any config steps in your container. The interactive (`-it`) login is mostly to help develop/debug containers. Avoid any manual steps in your deployment.

```
docker run -p 443:443 container-name bash -c "myconfigscript.sh && exec lein run"
```

Comment: @MarcYoung That's another use case. If your application needs to spawn other processes then yes you need to use some init system. In many cases however you want to perform some work before your application starts, in that case the `exec` call is simpler.

Comment: And what should the `myconfigscript.sh` file do? Ask the user some questions and generate the config file? Note that it's not enough in my case -- the user also should place an SSL certificate to the `web-service`'s directory

Comment: So you would to create a custom Leiningen environment on the fly for new users to your system?

Answer (score -1):

If you are in the shell session on the container Ctrl + C will allow you to disconnect without the container stopping.